# Is there a limit of loans you can ask?

Tags: europa-universalis-iv

**Is there a limit of loans you can ask ?**

If yes, what determine this limit ? Is it the same for every country ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The limit is determined by your economic power (i.e. total income), the current year and the size of the loans (6, 12 or 24 months of income, default is 12, but it may be changed with an event after getting the national bank idea).

You can always check it by hovering over the loan buttons in the economic tab.
Being forced to take a loan while at your limit will trigger bankruptcy.

There are no limits to taking loans from other countries, though the AI will usually never grant loans.